# Angular - ngOnChanges() not getting executed on property change

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
@Component {
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: 'app.component.css'
}
export class App implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  prop = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.prop = 'something';
  }
  
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes);
  }
}
```

I'm expecting to get the console log from `ngOnChanges()` when I change the `prop` property via `ngOnInit()` method. But it's not working. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lifeCycle hook *OnChanges* is only triggered for an *@Input()* property when the value is changed in the parent component.

Edit regarding the comments :

In order to listen to a prop changes inside a component, you can change it to a Subject :

```
prop: Subject<string> = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  this.prop.next('something');
  this.prop.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
}

onClick(value: string) {
  this.prop.next(value);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get notified on property change inside a component?

Comment: Not directly. You can change it into a subject so you can subscribe to it. I update my answer.